How to prevent Google from changing the order of logged in accounts?
This happens on all the browsers randomly, most often when some account gets logged off, but also on other occassions. And if you have cached/stored URLs like these:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=1

with 1 user ID in this case, they all get messed up and bring you to an account where they might be completely irrelevant.
Is there any way to configure the accounts to always have constant order, without relogging all of them in specific order?

Perhaps there is an alternate approach to specifying the account to use with a particular web-app (instead of relying on an order that is outside your control). For example, for Gmail, have you looked at this answer to Can I form a direct URL to a particular Gmail account?

It's not. I'm asking specifically about Google and how they save sessions. Browsers don't define how a web service remembers accounts and in what order, neither how the URLs and their slugs are assigned to them. It could perhaps also fit in SU, but I'm looking also for solutions in Google interface, which most likely don't exist as of now, but could in the future.

You're right. That was silly of me. Given that,  it is pointless to ask  to control how Google tracks the account order. There are lots of open questions about this all over, and practically speaking, the issue shouldn't be about how Google tracks the login account, but your ability to click on a bookmark accross machines and sessions and have it point to the correct account in a particular web app. The question should be oriented as a web app question. If it is not about a Web app then it becomes, not about a web app.

Thanks for pointing to the other question. It's a nice workaround for certain services, but it doesn't seem to work with all, e.g. Google Maps.

I get it but this is a web-app-centered site so if there is a particular web app it doesn't work for,  tailor the question specifically to that web app.  Good luck!
